# Get authentication code from redirect uri using OAuth 2.0

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, python-requests, spotify

I'm making a local api client for spotify which requires a OAuth 2.0 authentication. I'm only able to get the authentication code from the redirect uri when I open the GET request in a browser. Is there a way to get the authentication code using requests without having to use the browser?

The response object here doesn't have the authentication code

```
auth_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
res = requests.get(auth_url, params={
            "client_id": "*****************",
            "response_type": "code",
            "redirect_uri": "https://example.com/callback/", 
            "scope": "user-read-currently-playing"
            })
```

**TL;DR** how to get OAuth 2 authentication code from redirect uri using python code